# In precisely which scenarios does C throw a segmentation fault?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, coredump

I know that in the case of accessing arrays out of bounds:

```
int arr[2]; 
arr[3] = 10;
```

C will throw a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` during runtime.

However, C does not check out of bounds accesses with other stuff such as `strcpy()`.

I want to know exactly which cases would cause a segmentation fault, and which ones do not.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/core-dump-segmentation-fault-c-cpp/

Comment: accessing memory you don't own is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). You _hope_ that this results in a seg fault, which indicates there is a problem for you to find and fix. But "undefined behavior" means just that.. anything can happen, including no seg fault and the appearance your code is working just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Accessing any memory you don't own is undefined behaviour. This simply means that the C standard does not require anything at all from the compiler to deal with the situation.

Since C strives to be an efficient language, compilers rarely (ever?) will issue machine code that provides for run-time checks on such things. They may or may not issue warnings or errors if the violation is detectable at compile time.

The essence of this is: Any error message, including segfault, that you get at run-time, is usually coming from the OS. On older systems / OSs, or even today on smaller (embedded) systems, this kind of memory management was/is not available, and memory access violations could just crash your entire system, possibly a long time after the original violation occurred. Or nothing at all could happen. Or even more insidious things like data corruption.

So be happy to have the safety net of modern OS's virtual memory management systems, but don't rely on them to prevent programming errors to do greater damage, or to detect such errors in the first place.

You should also experiment a bit with tools like valgrind, which offer much run-time analytics and error detection for your programs; one can learn a lot this way.

BTW: As selbie pointed out in a comment, your code likely overwrites part of the function's stack frame or activation record. The reason for this is that the stack on most machines grows downwards (new memory is allocated at smaller addresses), but array indexing moves upwards. Many compilers include the option of compiling with a 'stack canary' which can detect stack corruption in the run-time. This is a very useful feature during development & testing, and also provides *some* defense against malware which tries to exploit exactly such buffer overruns.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Segmentation faults occur only when we access memory that the OS did not allocate to the process. But sometimes, on an out of bound access, we may still be within the allocated memory of the program overall, thus not giving us segmentation faults - it will give garbage values in that case.

Comment: The reason why your example in the question results in a seg fault is because you are likely corrupting the stack. The crash occurs when the function returns. If you allocated that array with `malloc` and then inserted a value out of range, it's not always guaranteed that you are going to hit the seg fault reliably.